# Variable scope in a for-loop initialization statement Java

Tags: java, variables

In Java, what is variable scope in for-loop initialization if the variable declared outside of for loop? I have two cases below:

1. invalid case

```
// Invalid, unknown i
      private int i  = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        
      }
```

2. valid case

```
  private int i  = 0;
  void foo() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      
    }
  }
```

In the second case, why i can be accessed?

Comment: Why are you trying to declare a variable `private` inside a method?

Comment: The scope of the variable "cares" only about where it's defined, not whether or not it's used in a loop or where that loop is.

Comment: In the second case, why i can be accessed?

Comment: In the second case, i is an instance variable. In the first case, it shouldn't compile.